# Why would email deliver normally when MX Lookup test returns "DNS Record not found"?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

**Background:** CentOS 8, Postfix, Dovecot, Digital Ocean droplet.

My mail server can send and receive emails without a problem.
My DNS records include an `A`, `AAAA` and `MX` record for my mail server.

```
A mail.example.com     directs to 10.10.10.1
AAAA mail.example.com     directs to 1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111
MX mail.example.com     mail handled by mail.example.com
```

However when I tested my setup on [MXtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) the MX Lookup test returned an error.

```
Category: MX        Result: DNS Record not found
```

**Question)** Which record is missing or misconfigured?  I'm not sure what to add or repair in this instance especially since emails can be sent and received.

Comment: Unless your domain is example.com, we can't help you. Now, if you'll share the actual domain with us we can tell you what we see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your domain does not have an MX record. But an MTA is listening on the A record's IP, and that is the fallback of SMTP in case there is no MX record.

Comment: You were right.  My MX record was setup but I had done it wrong.  It should have been `Type: MX    Hostname: example.com    Value: mail handled by mail.example.com`

Comment: The original design was the other way around: `MX` was an override of the `A` record. Originally `MX` was for exceptional cases, such as relaying to servers on other networks like UUCP or BITNET. It has since become the expected case.